# Highlight SelectedItem on start-up

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to highlight (with changing the background) `SelectedItem` in the collection on start-up.
I have a data template to define the items. I can use a border to set the background. In the moment the highlight is done when an item is selected.

```cs
<DataTemplate.Triggers>                       
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=syncfusion:CarouselItem}}" Value="True">
       <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

But because on start-up the `SelectedItem` is already active, it seems logic to be also highlighted.

Comment: What type of object is this? And what does your XMAL hierarchy look like? Its hard to write an answer without that information

Comment: It is a carousel from sycnfusion. The ItemSource is bind to some collection,and the selecteditem is bind to one item from that collection, and i'm trying to highlight just the SelectedItem on start-up. After that the highlight is done by a trigger on IsSelected prop

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just selecting an item in the collection to ensure that one is selected? You could declare a property of the type of the items that populate the collection to data bind to the `ItemsControl.SelectedItem` property. Then in your code behind, or view model, you can do this (assuming your collection control is data bound to a data collection named `Items`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

...

```
Items = FillCollectionWithItems();
if (Items.Count > 0) SelectedItem = Items[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be the item is Selected, but not Focused, and the system color for selected but not focused is usually a really light gray that's hard to see.

You could try ensuring that the item has Focus on load if this is the case, or overwrite the [system colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) for the control.

Here's an example that overwrites the `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush` color for a control:

```
<SomeControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}" Color="Red"/>
</SomeControl.Resources>
```